# WiFi is not working and doesn't show up in Network Manager and System settings

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless, additional-drivers

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and my wifi icon has just disppeared. It doesn't even show up in System Settings. The result of `sudo lspci -nn` is:

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
```

The result of `sudo lshw -C network` is:

```
 *-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Network controller
   product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
   vendor: Ralink corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:b5510000-b551ffff


*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 08
   serial: a0:1d:48:df:4a:d1
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-2_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=10.51.1.199 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:42 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b5404000-b5404fff memory:b5400000-b5403fff
```

I have also tried:

`sudo service network-manager stop`

```
 sudo rm /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
 sudo service network-manager start
```

I also tried by changing the additional drivers as suggested in a video:

Screenshot of Software & Updates->Additional Drivers:

[image: Screenshot of Software & Updates->Additional Drivers]

[Result of System Diagnostics](https://paste.ubuntu.com/17111996/)

[Result of : sudo systemctl status networking.service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/17112074/)

But to no avail .

Please help !!

Comment: What happens when you try `sudo systemctl start networking.service` ?

Comment: [main]Nothing[main]

Comment: Can you add the output of `sudo systemctl status networking.service` to your question?

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `blacklist rt2800pci` in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and rt2800pci should be the kernel module to support your wifi.

To fix this, open a terminal window and enter

```
sudo sed -i 's/blacklist rt2800pci/#blacklist rt2800pci/' /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Reboot and wifi should work.  The code simply replaces `blacklist rt2800pci` with `#blacklist rt2800pci`  The additional `#` at the beginning of the line makes it a comment